# Google App Script Array - Why Return Undefined?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written something like this on Google App Script:

```
var crossup = [];
var i;
var name_cell;
var cross_up_cell;
cross_up_cell = sheet.getRange(2, 1);
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
var ticker;
var value1;
ticker = name_cell.offset(0, i).getDisplayValue();
value1 = cross_up_cell.offset(0, i).getDisplayValue();
if (value1=="YES") {crossup.push(ticker)};
}
```

What I had in mind: I thought I was going to output an array of value1 with the value "ticker" assign by getDisplayValue(), but as I output the array, it turns out that I received a series of "undefined" as output.

To be exact, whenever value1 is really "YES" on my Google SpreadSheet, the if statement did "push" "ticker" into the crossup array, but instead of pushing back the display value, it pushed back "undefined"...

Help!!! How come?

Answer (score 0):

The var **name_cell** isn't set.
Use code below, where

> cross_up_cell = sheet.getRange(2, 1);

```
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  cross_up_cell = sheet.getRange(2, 1);
```

Comment: Hello Thiago, I think it might not be the reason, I actually had the codes before the quoted lines:

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("something");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PASTEVALUE");

But it still doesn't work... Any other ideas???

Many thanks!!!

Comment: might it be that I cannot push something like "object.method" into an google app script array somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You never fully define `name_cell`, so your `offset` method for `ticker` returns an `undefined` cell/range, which then gets pushed to your `crossup` array.

Your syntax is a bit odd with initializing and assigning variables, so I've rewritten the snippet you posted:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(*****).getSheetByName("PASTEVALUE"), //get sheet
      crossup = []; //initialize empty crossup array

  //get the display values in row 2 up to column 12
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 12).getDisplayValues()[0]; 
  //get the display values in row 3 up to column 12, assuming they are in row 3
  var ticker = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, 12).getDisplayValues()[0];

  //initialize increment in for loop, i's value goes from 0 to values.length-1 (the array's full index range)
  for (var i in values) {
    //if the value in row 2, column "i" is "YES", push the value of row 3, column "i" to the crossup Array
    if (values[i] == "YES") crossup.push(ticker[i]); 
  }

  //do stuff with crossup...

}
```

Instead of incrementally offsetting cells, you can use `getDisplayValues()` of an extended `Range` (full row or column, or multiple rows and columns) to get a 2D array, which I think is much quicker to increment through.

Either defining `name_cell` in your example or editing to make the syntax changes should fix your problem. Let me know if you have any problems or questions.